# What is the meaning of 'metaphasis'?

Tags: meaning

In his book *Mother Tongue* Bill Bryson discusses the Revd. William Spooner, who gave his name to *Spoonerisms*. He comments saying 'What is certain is that Spooner suffered from a kind of ***metaphasis of thought***, if not also of word'.

The OED has never heard of *metaphasis*, and Google/Wikipedia don't recognise it at all.

Is it possible that Bryson is himself guilty of something like a *Spoonerism* or *Malapropism* himself?

Comment: 'metathesis' is probably what was intended. Maybe it's a typo or transcription error?

Comment: Perhaps he was presuming to arrogate on productivity. Lots of people on ELU seem to think that all nonce words should be considered part of the lexicon.

Comment: ***Metaphysis*** ? : Change of form; transformation. http://www.thefreedictionary.com/metaphysis

Comment: You are probably right. Well done. Why don't you supply that as an answer.

Comment: @Josh61 That is interesting since *metaphysis* is a bone in the human anatomy. There is only one reference to the word as meaning *transformation*, or *metamorphosis* in the OED and that is from Dr Samuel Johnson's dictionary of 1755. I am now wondering if Dr Johnson had his wires crossed on this one.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Umm, perhaps. But my hunch is that Mitch got it right with *metathesis* and that Bill Bryson has taken *metaphysis* from Dr Samuel Johnson (and then corrupted it to *metaphasis*), of whom he is a great fan, and eulogises his dictionary to the skies. Perhaps Bryson has a copy which he uses for everyday purposes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wiktionary  shows its usage from 1953, probably from the term used in biology as an alternative form of ***metaphysis***.

[Metaphasis](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/metaphasis) (uncountable):

> ***The accidental transposition of part of the sounds of two words in a phrase; The production of spoonerisms.***
>
> - 1953, Sir Ernest Barker, Age and Youth: Memories of Three Universities ; And, Father of the Man, page 46:
>     'Oxford's great metaphasiarch', as Punch once called him, ***was seldom guilty of metaphasis,*** or the transposition of sounds. What he transposed was ideas.
> - 1979, Gore Vidal, Kalki, ISBN 0345278739, page 31:
>     ***Dr. Ashok suffered from a mild form of metaphasis. He made Spoonerisms.***
> - 1986 October 23, Adrian Room, “Letters”, London Review of Books:
>     But couldn’t it be that there is a distinction to be made between ‘metaphasis’ and ‘metathesis’? The OED defines the latter as ‘the interchange of position between sounds or letters in a word’ (my italics). An example would be Old English bridd becoming modern bird. ***This leaves ‘metaphasis’ free to describe what Spooner did: transpose sounds between different words, like his classic ‘our queer Dean’.***
> - 2009, Denise Sutherland, Word Searches For Dummies, ISBN 0470453664, page 76:
>     ***The technical term for this transposition is metaphasis.***

***[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=metaphasis&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmetaphasis%3B%2Cc0): metaphasis***. The term appears in Ngram from the 50s mainly in biological but also literary contexts.

Comment: Good find. But do you have any data on the corpus size used by Wiktionary, and its inclusion policies? //// I've found: 'Attestation

“Attested” means verified through[2]

clearly widespread use, or
use in permanently recorded media, conveying meaning, in at least three independent instances spanning at least a year ' [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Wiktionary:Criteria_for_inclusion). Seems over-generous to me.

Comment: Sorry: can't find anything relevant (except for the slimming tip).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - http://archive.spectator.co.uk/article/20th-november-1953/62/age-and-youth-by-sir-ernest-barker-oxford-universi. I find the link between metaphasis and metaphysis very interesting and plausible. The information offered by wiktionary regarding this term is worth being taken into consideration in my opinion.

Comment: Well done for finding that. I may report this conversation to the OED to see what they think. On the previous occasion I did this I got a very helpful early reply. But I think you and @Edward would be interested to see Bryson's account of Spooner. On one occasion he rebuked a student saying 'I thought you read the lesson badly today'. 'But, sir, I didn't read the lesson' protested the student. 'Ah' said Spooner, 'I thought you didn't' and walked on. On another occasion he approached a fellow don and said 'Do come to dinner tonight to meet our new Fellow, Casson'. (continued)

Comment: @WS2n- please note also the Ngram I have attached.

Comment: (B.Fwd) - The man answered 'But, Warden, I am Casson'. To which Spooner replied 'Never mind come all the same'. These type of remarks sound not a thousand miles away from the confabulations that my dear father used to relate between the age of 98 and 99 and three-quarters (when he died). In psychiatry a *confabulation* is an imaginary experience that the subject devises to compensate for loss of memory*.

Answer (score 2):

**metaphasis**
n. Transposing sounds or letters in a word or phrase.

It seems that the first recorded instance of this word was nearly 30 years ago.

> The accidental transposition of part of the sounds of two words is
>   technically metaphasis, but for more than 100 years it has been hung
>   around the neck of an otherwise obscure classics don. —“In praise of…
>   Dr Spooner,” The Guardian, December 13, 2010
>
> 1986 (earliest) SIR: Patrick Hughes is right (LRB, 24 July):
>   ‘metaphasis’ is not in the OED. In fact, as far as I can see, it is
>   not in any dictionary. But couldn’t it be that there is a distinction
>   to be made between ‘metaphasis’ and ‘metathesis’? The OED defines the
>   latter as ‘the interchange of position between sounds or letters in a
>   word’ (my italics). An example would be Old English bridd becoming
>   modern bird. This leaves ‘metaphasis’ free to describe what Spooner
>   did: transpose sounds between different words, like his classic ‘our
>   queer Dean’. —Adrian Room, “Letters,” London Review of Books, October
>   23, 1986 -

*[both quotes from Word Spy](http://wordspy.com/index.php?word=metaphasis)*

Comment: Interesting. It still has not got into the OED. Of course Bryson referred to Spooner having a *kind of **metaphasis** of thought, if not only of word*. Bryson does give some examples of his confused thought patterns.